# Securing MVC application directory on a Virtual machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently hosted a MVC application on machine and in solution I have a folder UploadedDocuments which i wants to secure. Actually when i browse URL like www.xyz.com/UploadedDocument it lists all the file even i didn't login to website

Note: Using Microsoft Interop for PDF conversion of docs in this directory.

wants to restrict the users who can browse folder but if a url with file name in folder and a user on website that is loggedin can access only with specified url 
like www.xyz.com/UploadedDocument/abc.docx(except www.xyz.com/UploadedDocument)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, ensure that directory browsing is disabled.

On the file system, remove read access for any "normal" user accounts or groups, and have only the app pool account that IIS is running under with modify access to the folder (ie the "iis apppool\[MyApplication]" account).

You say you're using Microsoft interop for conversion. Is the conversion happening within the MVC application, or do you have another application / service performing the conversion? If the latter, also ensure that whatever account is running the other application / service has access to modify the folder.

Comment: when i do directory browsing disabled then website also not reachable.